# Changing HTML into DOM

Tags: java, html, dom

Is in Java (sic!) any function which could change HTML placed in string into DOM Tree?

Comment: Do you really mean Java or rather JavaScript?

Comment: YES,I do !
I want to do it in java

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your quest @oneat. What is your goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug: Have a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) (an open source Java HTML library I just released). Gives a CSS and jquery-like syntax to getting at the data, in addition to the tradition DOM methods.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```